Foreign street names in Japanese
I know that most streets in Japan don't have names, but I have a question: What if I want to name a foreign street talking in Japanese? For example, in my city, there's a street named "Calle Cielo" ("Sky Street" in Spanish). How should I say this in Japanese?
At first, I thought シエロストリート would be the best option because ストリート is the closer I can get to the occidental concept of street, but even then I ask myself: should I translate "Cielo" (sky) as シエロ focusing on the pronunciation? Or it would make more sense to say 空ストリート focusing in the meaning of the word that names the street?
This is really confusing, but hopefully someone can enlighten me.

Most streets in Japan don't have names? I am intrigued, can you tell me more?

@DannyBeckett Most streets have only numbers. Read Japanese addressing system.

@Arfrever That's very interesting, thank you!

I have checked translations of some well-known streets:

Downing Street → ダウニング街{がい}

Pennsylvania Avenue → ペンシルベニア大{おお}通{どお}り

Wall Street → ウォール街{がい}

Avenue des Champs-Élysées → シャンゼリゼ通{どお}り

Bankova Street → バンコヴァ通{どお}り

Tverskaya Street → トゥヴェルスカヤ通{どお}り

Leninsky Avenue → レーニンスキー大{おお}通{どお}り


By analogy, シエロ街{がい} or シエロ通{どお}り would be good translations of Calle Cielo.

Your answer was really helpful! Now im curious about the differences between 街 and 通り, The "Calle Cielo" im talking about is a small street adjacent to an abandoned cemetary, theres nothing important there, just cute stray cats. maybe with that in mind is easier to choose one! I dont know how to put photos but in case you want to see it yourself search in google maps "Calle Cielo Cádiz" and put it on street view :)

@mariomariomario So this is a street in city Cádiz in Spain?

exactly, im from there!!

@mariomariomario About 街{がい} / 通{どお}り, there was another question, but without real details in currently available answer.

I think シエロストリート is one of the best translation. There are a lot of loan words in Japanese and they are basically translated based on pronunciation. For example, New York is usually spelled ニューヨーク in Japanese.
Another great candidate is シエロ通り. As you can see "Cielo Street" consists of a proper noun (Cielo) and a common noun (Street). (Sorry if I'm wrong about "Cielo" being a proper noun. ) In this case, the common noun is sometimes translated in Japanese and proper noun is translated based on pronunciation. Here are some examples.

London Bridge = ロンドン橋
Mississippi River = ミシシッピ川
Baker Street = ベーカー通り

Generally proper nouns are translated based on pronunciation, not a meaning basis. The exception is the original proper nouns are in Chinese characters. For example the Chinese city 上海  is also spelled 上海 in Japanese. So, if you translate it as 空ストリート, people might misunderstand it as something derived from Chinese character culture.

Ahhh I see, thank you for your time!! I had no idea about that translation dynamic between Chinese and Japanese, would have been a huge problem...

As others mention, シエロ通り is one of the best options.
シエロ・ストリート is also possible, but it seems there are no good reason to choose it over シエロ通り because the original name is not in English (and ストリート is a transcription of English word "street"). Instead, if you suppose the readers are familiar enough with Spanish (or with your area), you can treat the whole street name as a proper noun and transcribe as カイェ・シエロ (or you may change カイェ to カジェ, カリェ, or カシェ according to the local pronunciation).
The word 通り is not specific to street, but potentially refers to avenue, road, boulevard (calle, avenida, etc...). So if you think the distinction is crucial in your context, it may be also helpful to write the original name by side in parentheses, as follows: シエロ通り（Calle Cielo）
PS
In general, if there is a convention, follow it: certain streets have already a fixed convention how to mention it in Japanese, especially if it is a tourist spot.

thank you for your comment, now I see it makes a lot of sense to discard ストリート.

tl;dr
I would write it is （カイエ・カーレ＊）シエロ.  I would say it as 「（カイエ・カーレ＊）シエロ」という道・通り.

Explanation
This is an interesting question and made me think quite a bit.  And I believe it is actually a lot more complicated than it initially seems.  Let me start off by saying I'm making 2 assumptions:

Your street Calle Cielo is in a country where "Calle" is not recognized as an official street suffix.
What if I want to name a foreign street talking in Japanese?? includes writing, not just speaking.

In light of these 2 assumptions, I'm going to disagree with all the other answers here.  (If assumption 1 is wrong, then the following explanations may not be applicable.)
Of course "Calle Cielo" means "Sky Street" in Spanish.  But according to the United States Postal Service standards, while there is an official USPS abbreviation for "Calle", it is not an official street suffix.  And Japanese words like （大・本）通り and 街 are definitely suffixes.  Thus, I would consider "Calle" as part of the street name, and not try to turn it into the street type/designation.
I live in southern New Mexico, and we have a big street here named "Avenida de Mesilla".  You can see on Google Maps in Japanese＊ that it is simply called アヴェニダ・デ・メシラ; it is not メシラ本通 or anything like that.  The "Avenida" is not made into a Japanese suffix.  You can also see several other "Calle"s here written as 「カーレ」＊.
(Click to expand)

Similarly for town/city names with "Villa" or "Ciudad", it just becomes (ビヤ・ビージャ) or シウダード as part of the name, not the suffixes ～村 or ～市.



Strangely enough, "Ciudad de Mexico" is just メキシコシティ...  ‍♂️
Of course, this all happens to be in the familiar contexts of maps and apps.  In legal/governmental contexts within Japan, it could be very different.  "Cuidad Juárez" could very well be written as ファレス市 in those contexts.  But I do not have any knowledge of those contexts...
That's all to say that I would consider "Calle" to be part of the street name, and not try to translate it to a street suffix in Japanese.

Conversely, think of it this way:  Suppose you told your Japanese friend you live on シエロストリート or シエロ通り or 空ストリート.  Now suppose that friend wants to send you a letter.  They're going to try to reverse-translate that into "Cielo Street" or "Cielo Road" or "Sky Street".  And you're NEVER going to receive that letter!!  In fact, those may all be distinct streets in a big enough city, and someone else could end up with your letter!  That's why I'd just stick with （カイエ・カーレ＊）シエロ.


＊Google Maps names in Japanese 1) often do not reflect the correct pronunciation of Spanish words, and 2) may differ from names in other mapping systems.

I mostly agree with your answer, but it sometimes would be better to include 通り even if you write it, since it is only clue telling that it is not a name of district nor restaurant but a street to readers not familiar with Spanish.

Regarding your argument about sending back letters: I think that any transcription (in whatever direction) should not be relied upon, since there can be many groups of words differing in original pronunciation or spelling, but which look the same after transcription, e.g. into Japanese katakana. Examples: Low / Row / Roe (all attested with Street) → ロウ, Meat / Meet / Mete (at least Mete Street is attested) → ミート.

First of all, thank you for your time because your answers is really thought provoking and you brought up a lot of interesting viewpoints and cool stuff I havent considered at all. What really shocked me the most is that you did view Calle as part of the street name, because at least here in Andalucia, Spain, I think it works like a suffix (or at least everybody thinks it does) because when they change a name they always mantain Calle or Avenida or Callejón etc. The only cases in which this doesnt happen is when the name doesnt have a suffix.

What you said about the letter is fascinating but in my case I wanted to know how to write Calle Cielo because of a song im writting named "Los gatos de la calle cielo" (The cats of the Cielo street". Its written in japanese and im struggling a lot but it will be worth it!

@rk03 I have thought that too, im interested in people getting that its the name of a street because its not a famous one, good point!

@Arfrever Also a really good point, I agree with you. Thanks for your time :)

@mariomariomario and istrasci: Japanese 街{がい} and 通り{どおり} are suffixes (suffix is part of word attached at the end; prefix is part of word attached at the beginning), but Spanish calle is an independent noun, and in Spanish language (similarly to Latin and French), adjectives are usually placed after nouns, not before them.

@mariomariomario  When USA were expanding in 19th century, previous Spanish/French/other names of cities, towns, villages, streets etc. were often kept (or abbreviated), although English persons use English pronunciation of these names. E.g. San Francisco, Los Angeles instead of Saint Francis, The Angels. istrasci's answer seems to be mostly about handling of names in such areas, instead of in Spain.

@Arfrever ohhh I see, in that case I have no doubt left, I will use 通り.
